# Access all passwords in the iCloud keychain

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, security, keychain

I'm currently able to retrieve every password in the user keychain thanks to the `SecKeychain` API, with the `SecItemCopyMatching` method.
But if I specify the `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute to true, I only get the password I added myself previously with the `SecItemAdd` method.

Is there a way to also get the passwords stored by the system or more particularly by Safari?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to also get the passwords stored by the system or more particularly by Safari?

No.  If you think about it, that would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Well the method would ask the user's password of course. So I don't think so.

Comment: @Caktuspace Yes, it would.  You are adding an "all access" feature to a system that does not have said feature.   Such a feature adds a huge new vector for malware to steal information from the user.

Comment: I didn't think about that. It perfectly makes sense. Thanks

Comment: I don't get why that would be any more insecure than accessing a regular keychain. The user gets prompted for his password if he wants to access an item that doesn't belong to him. He can still say no. Thats also how it works for the System keychain. Why should the iCloud chain be any different?